# Three-Point correlation function in cosmology

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, greens-functions

I have been studying this review article on [Non-Gaussianity from inflation](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0406398). It was mentioned that $n$-point correlation function can be obtained by the expression
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\langle\delta\tilde{\chi}_{k_1}\delta\tilde{\chi}_{k_2}...\delta\tilde{\chi}_{k_N}\rangle=-i\int_{\tau_{0}}^\tau d\tau'\langle0|[\delta\tilde{\chi}_{k_1}\delta\tilde{\chi}_{k_2}...\delta\tilde{\chi}_{k_N},H_{int}(\tau')]|0\rangle.
\end{equation}
For two-point correlation function, the definition is $$\langle0|\delta\tilde{\chi}_{k}(\tau,\vec{k})\delta\tilde{\chi}_{k'}(\tau,\vec{k}')|0\rangle=\delta^{(3)}(\vec{k}+\vec{k}')G(k,\tau,\tau')$$ where $G(k,\tau,\tau')$ is Green's function.
For a cubic scalar field interaction term $\frac{\lambda}{3!}\chi^3$, the three point function can be written as
$$\langle\delta\tilde{\chi}_{k_1}\delta\tilde{\chi}_{k_2}\delta\tilde{\chi}_{k_3}\rangle=-i\lambda\int_{-\infty}^{\tau}\frac{d\tau'}{H\tau'}\delta^{(3)}(\vec{k_1}+\vec{k_2}+\vec{k_3})[G(k_1,\tau,\tau')G(k_2,\tau,\tau')G(k_3,\tau,\tau')-G^{*}(k_1,\tau,\tau')G^{*}(k_2,\tau,\tau')G^{*}(k_3,\tau,\tau')].$$
Now I cannot understand how this expression is obtained for the three point function. As per as I know, these ensembled averages are computed using Wick's theorem in which fully contracted expressions are considered. So there will be field terms which by Wick's theorem can be contracted to 3 two-point functions. So I understood there will be 3 Green's function together. But for Wick's theorem there are several terms of different order, so why only two of them survives? Also why the integration limit changes from the first expression to the second expression?